# What is the correct type of Javascript array to use when building a questionnaire?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm building a single-page questionnaire app and I'm not sure what is the correct way to build my arrays for the questions. Also, is it bad practice to mix types of questions in this manner? (Single choice, multi-choice in same array?) Basically, I'm still trying to understand the advantages/disadvantages of the two basic approaches I've seen.

Option 1:

```
var hygiene = [

  {
    pageheader: "Self-Care"
  }

  {
    q: "When was your last shower?",
    choicetype: "radio",
    a1: "Today",
    a2: "Yesterday",
    a3: "Two days ago",
    a4: "I don't know"
  }

  {
    q: "How much do you weigh today?",
    choicetype: "keypad"
  }

  {
    q: "Do you take any medications?",
    choicetype: "radio",
    a1: "Yes",
    a2: "No"
  }

  {
    q: "Which medications?",
    choicetype: "multiselect",
    a1: "Zostavax",
    a2: "Percocet",
    a3: "Actemra",
    a4: "Cimzia",
    a5: "Relprevv"
  }

];
```

Option 2:

```
var hygiene = {

  pageheader: "Self-Care",

  question1: [
    "When was your last shower?", "radio", "Today", "Yesterday",
    "Two days ago", "I don't know"
  ],

  question2: [
    "How much do you weigh today?", "keypad"
  ],

  question3: [
    "Do you take any medications?", "radio", "Yes", "No"
  ],

  question4: [
    "Which medications?", "multiselect", "Zostavax", "Percocet",
    "Actemra", "Cimzia", "Relprevv"
  ]

};
```

Comment: This is really not important, just pick one and don't waste your time on it.

Comment: I'd use JSON: http://json.org/example.html

Comment: Neither example accurately represents the structure of the content that you have.

Comment: You need to understand the difference between objects and arrays.

Comment: @Diodeus: JSON is a string format, it is *not* the same as a JavaScript array/object.  JSON is a data transport format that just happens to resemble JavaScript arrays/objects.

Comment: @Diodeus: What does data interchange have to do with this?

Comment: JSON is a structure, not a data exchange protocol.

Comment: @Diodeus, ["JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a lightweight data-interchange format."](http://www.json.org/)

Comment: @Diodeus: JSON is Unicode data. It is *precisely* a data exchange protocol.

Comment: If it's a protocol - what's the start signal? the stop signal? the error message? There aren't any because this is a DATA OBJECT (or a FORMAT). HTTP is a protocol. JSON is certainly not.

Comment: What's with the down voting? Dude just wants to know if he's on the right track.

Comment: @Diodeus: Sorry, I used your chosen word. Doesn't change the fact that it's a data interchange format, and has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Yeah, why the down votes? I'm just a lame beginner trying to get where you guys are. Thanks for all the comments and help, by the way. Just seeing the suggestions helps a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My recommendation is not to use either of them, but the following:

```
var hygiene = {

    pageheader: "Self-Care",

    questions: [

        {
            question: "When was your last shower?",
            choicetype: "radio",
            answers: [
                "Today",
                "Yesterday",
                "Two days ago",
                "I don't know"
            ]
        },

        {
            question: "How much do you weigh today?",
            choicetype: "keypad"
        },

        {
            question: "Do you take any medications?",
            choicetype: "radio",
            answers: [
                "Yes",
                "No"
            ]
        },

        {
            question: "Which medications?",
            choicetype: "multiselect",
            answers: [
                "Zostavax",
                "Percocet",
                "Actemra",
                "Cimzia",
                "Relprevv"
             ]
         }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Add some reasons why and I'll upvote this.

Comment: Roughly, the "{}" are used as "classes" to define attributes. The "[]" are used to define collections of definitions.

Comment: I meant within the answer, but that'll do I guess. The whole point is that your answer gives a suggested structure (which is good) with no reasoning as to *why*.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 is much better than option 2, because you specify the variables and gave each of the string meaningful names to be used later in your code.

It depends on the readability of your code later if you had a large chunk of questionaires. If you had 100 of these in a file, would you prefer 1 or 2?

Comment: +1. Option 2 is essentially a jsonized CSV format which has only the benefit of being somewhat smaller (in terms of bytes transfered from server) due to the omitted keys for the field names. If you were transferring TONS of data, then it would be worth considering Option 2. Otherwise, Option 1 is more human readable and easier to work with.

Comment: Agreed. If there are tons of these data, emitting them for optimization would be a different scenario all together.